# compiler optimization implementation

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, implementation

Actually I am making a major project in implementing compiler optimization techniques. I already know about the existing techniques, but I am confused what technique to choose and how to implement it.

Comment: Can you be more specific? For instance, it’s not clear what techniques you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

G'day,

What area of optimization are you talking about?

Compiler optimizations such as:

- loop optimizations
- dataflow optimizations
- static single assignment based optimizations
- code generator optimizations
- etc.
- etc.

Or optimization in the performance of the compiler itself, i.e. the speed with which it works?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a compiler to optimize, and if it wasn't written by you, look up the documentation to see what is missing. Otherwise, if it was written by you, you can start off with the simplest. The definition for the simplest will depend on the language your compiler consumes. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have over optimized your question .  Are you trying to decide where to start or trying to decide if some optimizations are worth implementing and others are not?  I would assume all of the existing techniques have a place and are useful depending on the code they come across.  If you are deciding which one to do first, pick the one you can do and do it.  Pick the low hanging fruit.  Get a few wins in your back pocket before you tackle a tough one and stumble and get frustrated.  I would assume the real trick is having all the optimizations there and working but coming up with a way to decide which ones produce something better for a particular program and which ones get in the way and make things worse.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, the thing to do is implement the simple, obvious optimizations and then let it rest. Certainly it is very interesting to try to do weird and wonderful optimizations to rectify things that the user could simply have coded a little better, but if you really want to try to clean up after poor coding or poor design, the user can always outrun you. [This is my favorite example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773)

My favorite example of compiler-optimizations-gone-nuts is Fortran compilers, where they go to such lengths to scramble code to shave a few hypothetical cycles that the code is almost impossible to debug, and typically the program counter is in there less than 1% of the time, so the effort is wasted.